# React Express TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, react-dom-server

I'm trying to render my react app on server incase the user has disabled javascript and also for better search result. But somewhere between export and using the function, I got the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error.

Here are some of my code

```
// serverRender.js
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import axios from 'axios';

const serverRender = () => {
    axios.get(`${config.serverUrl}/api/content`)
        .then(res => {
            return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                <App initialData={res.data.content} />
            );
        })
        .catch(console.error);
}

export default serverRender;
```

I then inject the code in my server.js

```
// server.js
import express from 'express';    
import serverRender from './serverRender';

const server = express();
server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    serverRender()
        .then(content => {
            res.render('index', {
                content
            });
        })
        .catch(console.error);
});
```

I also tried just

```
// serverRender.js
axios.get(`${config.serverUrl}/api/content`)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(
            ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                <App initialData={res.data.content} />
            )
        );
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

And I did see the rendered content on my console.
Please let me know what's wrong, thanks!

p.s. full error here

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at /.../server.js:19:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/...t/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at sass (/.../node_modules/node-sass-middleware/middleware.js:127:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: The error occurs in server.js, so it is `serverRender()` that is undefined. Is it correctly imported into your server.js file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a promise from your serverRender function if you want it to be 'thenable'. At the moment, you're not returning anything from that function.

```
// serverRender.js
const serverRender = () => {
return axios.get(`${config.serverUrl}/api/content`)
    .then(res => {
        return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <App initialData={res.data.content} />
        );
    })
    .catch(console.error);
}

export default serverRender;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning a promise from your serverRender.js function. In order to call `serverRender().then` you must return the promise from the serverRender function. The following will work - notice the implicit return:

```
const serverRender = () => (
    axios.get(`${config.serverUrl}/api/content`)
    .then(res => {
        return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <App initialData={res.data.content} />
        );
    })
    .catch(console.error);
);

export default serverRender;
```